# How to show $\nabla^\perp_X \eta =0$ when codimension is 1?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Pictures below are from do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry.

$f:M\rightarrow \overline M$ is immersion.  When codimension is 1, according to the book, there is $\nabla^\perp_X \eta=0$. But I need an extra condition $|\eta|=1$ to prove $\nabla^\perp_X \eta=0$.

What I do: since $|\eta|=1$, I have
$$
0=X\langle \eta,\eta\rangle=2\langle \overline \nabla_X \eta, \eta\rangle
$$
since codimension is 1,  the normal component of $\overline \nabla_X \eta$ is zero.
Namely $\nabla ^\perp_X \eta=0$.

But without $|\eta|=1$, I don't know how to prove it. In fact, I feel do Carmo miss the $|\eta|=1$, but I am not sure, so ask here.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Advice: It is not appropriate to upload most of pages of a book in this website.

Comment: Yes you need to assume $\lvert\eta\rvert$ is constant along integral curves of $X$, or else you pick up some $(X\log \lvert\eta\rvert)\eta$.

Comment: @C.F.G  Thanks for  your reminding. I have edit it.  Is it suitable?  I am not sure the reason of not appropriate to upload of most of pages. Is it  copyright? Or too much to read ?

Comment: @lanse7pty: I just worry about possible future problems (penalty, ...) for Math.SE and not other things.